# Open bookmark from bookmark bar in a new browser window - Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-bookmarks

I would like a way to set my bookmarks that are located in my bookmarks bar set to open with a new Chrome browser window.  I know if right click on them and select Open in New Window that works but I can't rely on my employees to do that step.  I would like to know if there is a way to do this without that step or with an extension?

Thank you
Jesse V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This opens a new tab rather than a new window, but you can use this as the URL in the bookmark, where ***url*** is the full web address.

```
javascript:window.open('url')
```

You have to include the single quotes.  For example:

```
javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com')
```

Alternatively, check out the answers to this question.  They're functional to get a new window, but more cumbersome.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab

Comment: The only problem with this is that the bookmark icon turns into a boring b&W icon, and not the fav icon of the website. Any way to fix that?